# Opening new file in new card - Okular

Tags: pdf, okular

I am sure that Okular has a following feature:

When I have already opened some .pdf file in Okular and then I will double-click on the another different .pdf file, Okular will open the second file in card, like a browser opens new page, instead of starting new Okular.

I just can't find how to enable that feature.
Thanks for any help and I aplogize for my english if I made any mistakes. Anyway I hope you will know what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tabbed interface in Okular.

[Read This.](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155515)